# Is it possible to create an interface between Teensy 3.2 and a DSP?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, signal-processing, teensy

I realize that this is a forum for Arduino but since the Teensy 3.2 is compatible with the Arduino IDE I thought it would be appropriate to ask the question here.

Anyway, can I create an interface between the Teensy 3.2 and a DSP, more specifically the TMS320C5534-Fixed-Point Digital Signal Processor and how could I go about it?

What I am trying to do do is capture an EEG and EoG (electrooculogram) signal, amplify it, filter the signal, use the DSP for ADC and signal processing and finally get this information from the DSP to the Teensy 3.2, which will then make a decision based on the signal obtained from the DSP.

Maybe this is a simple question but I couldn't find any answers online. I am pretty new to the world of microcontrollers.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why can't the DSP make the decision?

Comment: Because this involves obtaining and analyzing large amounts of data in real time. I though it would be faster If I used the DSP strictly for signal processing, which is intensive in this case, and then send the processed signal to the microcontroller to compare this information with the signal that I am looking for (i.e a certain brain wave and a pattern of eye movement). If a match was found then the microcontroller has to send a notification wireless to a mobile device saying that a match has been found.

Comment: the microcontroller would also monitor that there is good contact with the electrodes. So, I guess in short it would be to make the whole system faster, but I am not sure it that would be the result.

Comment: Yes, you can do it - for example if the data rates are moderate with an asynchronous serial interface.  But don't even bother trying to implement pattern recognition and decisioning on a microcontroller, until you have fully validated your algorithm on a PC, possibly against a large set of recorded data, and ultimately against data transmitted from the DSP sampler.  Until you have done that it is premature to select a micro as you can't reliably know what your computational and memory needs are.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of the serial interfaces and connect them together that way.  If Asyinc run as fast as reliable.